# Does IE9 not allow margins of 0px around checkbox (radio) inputs?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I updated some of my CSS styles to use normalize.css recently but discovered an apparent inconsistency - it seems that in IE9 it won't let me set margins 0 around a checkbox element. But I couldn't find any specific mention of the problem. [Here's an example of my test.](http://jsfiddle.net/2late2die/7JrdJ/) And here's a screenshot of what it looks like in Firefox, Chrome and IE9

[image: IE9 not respecting margin 0]

The reset styles are copy pasted from latest version of html5 boilerplate, which itself uses normalize.css by Nicolas Gallagher.

As I understood normalize.css, the idea is to keep some browser defaults but create a consistent layout for the components. However, from my quick testing, it looks like in fact there should not be a `margin:0` around (checkbox/radio) inputs in order to create consistent layout, [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/2late2die/7JrdJ/8/).

Having said that, smarter people than me worked on both normalize.css and html5 boilerplate, so either I'm missing something, or misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IE9 adds padding. I guess that reset script doesn't take that into account. Add `padding: 0` and you'll be set.

Comment: Ah ha! You're absolutely right - `margin:0; padding:0` does the trick, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

for my project I once rendered IE9 as IE8 by rendering it with meta tag of html

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8"/>
```

so the same css worked for both